# Unsync'd Git Repository in Dropbox

Tags: macos, git, file-permissions, dropbox

I have a git repository (and working directory) that is stored in my Dropbox so I can move back and forth between computers without having to commit or stash (read: without any effort at all). This is working great except for one minor annoyance that is becoming a major annoyance.

Every so often, I'll leave one computer in a fully committed state only to pick up on the other computer and find that a `git status` reports changes. Inevitably, those changes are related to permissions. What I'm not sure about is *why*? I assumed that it might be related to how Dropbox writes files on sync'd computers, but the `umask` on both systems is set to 0002. I would assume that value dictates the mode of files written/updated by Dropbox, but it wouldn't be the first time I'd be wrong.

I know I can just tell Git to ignore the file mode, but that's just masking the problem. I'd really like to understand it so I can make an informed decision of how to proceed.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

So here's a pretty decent representative example of a repository getting out of sync even though it's entirely contained within Dropbox. As we speak, my personal laptop is reporting a clean working directory for one of my projects:

```
$ git status
# On branch develop
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

My work laptop, though, reports a number of *untracked* files. Let me say that again: ***untracked*** files.

```
$ git status
# On branch develop
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   html/cake/console/libs/templates/
#   ...4 more files...
#   html/cake/tests/test_app/plugins/test_plugin/views/themed/
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

How can that be? My `~/.gitignore` file is also shared across both machines (not that any of these paths are excluded in an ignore file). Is there another component of Git--or maybe Dropbox--that could be in play here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've gotten this exact problem under the same circumstances.

To stop the files showing in `git status` you can set git to ignore file mode changes:

```
git config core.filemode false
```

This change is local to the git repository and will be synced along with the files.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check where you are setting your umask; it may be that dropbox is starting with a different umask than what your shell has.  However, I believe that git ignores the group/other permissions and is mostly concerned with the execute bit, which should not be affected by the umask.  Some thoughts for debugging:

- Can you reproduce this on-demand?  How?
- What operating systems are you synchronizing between?
- If you `git checkout -f` on the files in question, do they get the correct permissions?
- If you simply `chmod` a file on one system, does that change get propagated?

Comment: To your questions: no (I see this frequently, but not consistently), Both Macs, I'll try that, yes (at least in the short term). I'll keep drilling into it and follow up.

Comment: A Google search for dropbox and permissions on OS X returns http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20081009204908181 but I don't think that's relevant to the situation you are describing.

Comment: It's taken a while for this to reproduce itself. I haven't spent a ton of time trying, but I still can't reproduce it predictably. What I have now is one system where a few files have 644 perms and `git status` shows them unmodified. Another system where the same files are 644 and `git status` shows the perms modified from 755.

Answer (score 0):

The fact you are using Macs is relevant - the [Macworld Hints article](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20081009204908181) mentioned in a comment explains the issue (but read down to the comment that explains how to fix permissions with `chmod u+rwX` etc, rather than absolute permissions that may mess things up).

This [Dropbox Support answer](http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=38868&replies=12#post-322692) explains what's probably going on and how to fix it - related to how MacOS X Leopard (10.5) changed the default usage of ACLs.