# How to get list of symlinks in git repo

Tags: git, symlink

My goal is to get a list of all symlinks in a git repo (and then modify them).
The ls-tree works great but it does not show type of the object. Are there other ways to achieve my goal?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show the permission of a indexed file in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821263/show-the-permission-of-a-indexed-file-in-git)

Answer (score 0):

I found that 12000 is the symlink file mode